# euler_from_quaternion error when rpy is 0 90 0

Tags: tf

Hi I've got a problem with the function tf.euler_from_quaternion

I've got an end-effector's orientation using moveit_commander

and I want to convert quaternion to euler

When quaternion value is 0 0 0 1, euler_from_quaternion function convert very well (rpy:000)

But, when quaternion value is 0 0.707 0 0.707, I was expecting that rpy is 0 90 0, however uler_from_quaternion function gave me 82 89 80

when I inserted (0, 0.7, 0, 0.7 ), convert to 0 90 0
but this function couldn't convert (0, 0.707, 0, 0.707) I think there was a very little difference

I don't know why...
Someone else tell me the problem and how to fix this problem??

This is my code

def print_rpy(self):
global stop_loop
group = self.group

```
current_pose = group.get_current_pose().pose
init_x = current_pose.orientation.x
init_y = current_pose.orientation.y
init_z = current_pose.orientation.z
init_w = current_pose.orientation.w
print("init qua: ",init_x,init_y,init_z,init_w)

init_q_list = [init_x, init_y, init_z, init_w]
(init_roll, init_pitch, init_yaw) = euler_from_quaternion(init_q_list)
init_roll = round(init_roll * 180/pi,2)
init_pitch = round(init_pitch * 180/pi,2)
init_yaw = round(init_yaw * 180/pi,2)
print("init rpy : ", init_roll, init_pitch, init_yaw)

while (1):
  with stop_lock:
    if stop_loop:
      break

  current_pose = group.get_current_pose().pose
  current_x = current_pose.orientation.x
  current_y = current_pose.orientation.y
  current_z = current_pose.orientation.z
  current_w = current_pose.orientation.w
  print("current qua : ", current_x,current_y,current_z,current_w)

  q_list = [current_x, current_y, current_z, current_w]
  (r, p, y) = euler_from_quaternion(q_list, axes='sxyz')
  r = round(r * 180/pi,2)
  p = round(p * 180/pi,2)
  y = round(y * 180/pi,2)
  
  print("current rpy : ", r,p,y)
  error_r = init_roll-r
  error_p = init_pitch-p
  error_y = init_yaw-y
  
  print("error roll : ", error_r)
  print("error pitch : ", error_p)
  print("error yaw : ", error_y)

  rpy=str(error_r)+','+str(error_p)+','+str(error_y)
  # print(rpy)
  
  try:
    ser.write(rpy.encode('utf-8'))
    # print(ser.readline())
    print("connected", rpy)
  except:
    print("connect error")
```

Comment: Please edit your post to show us complete code that can be run. Are you using the `euler_from_quaternion()` function provided by ros?

Comment: I've edited the question. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

RPY angles have a singularity for pitch values of 90° and -90°. This means that, for a given orientation that yields a pitch of 90°, it is not possible to uniquely define the roll and yaw angles.

This is due to the X and Z axis being parallel, so there is no distinction between rotating around X or rotating around Z. I.e. the same orientation quaternion results from:

- rotating the full angle around X and zero around Z, or
- full angle around Z and zero around X, or
- any combination in between.

This is also called 'gimbal lock', see this nice animation on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock).

As a consequence, Quaternion to RPY conversion is ill-conditioned in the neighbourhood of a pitch value of +/- 90°.
Depending on the numerical precision, you can get varying results.

> and how to fix this problem??

This depends on your use case.

For my application, I simply rotated the reference frame of my end effector by 90°, so that the end-effector X-axis is never parallel to the world Z-axis in the motion range of my robot task. So I avoid that the RPY representation of {end effector} wrt {world} would be singular.

Alternatively, an option might be to use a different representation, e.g. ZXZ-Euler angles. But it is important to realise that **each** representation of an orientation by 3 variables has its singularities.

> How about to set my robot's orientation to 0, 89, 0 or 0, 91, 0??

A pitch angle of 89° or 91° corresponds to a different orientation than a pitch angle of 90°. So if you command your robot end effector to move to an orientation with a pitch of 89° or 91°, it will have a different physical orientation than for a pitch of 90°. Whether that *is* or *is not* acceptable for your task is something only you can assess.

Comment: Ah.. I've already known 'gimbal lock' phenomenon, but i didn't know that gimbal lock is applied to this conversion.. Think you for teaching me. Then what should I do to solve this problem? How about to set my robot's orientation to 0, 89, 0 or 0, 91, 0??

Answer (score 0):

I get the results I expect, which look very different from yours:

```
>>> import tf
>>> tf.transformations.euler_from_quaternion((0, 0.707, 0, 0.707))
(-0.0, 1.5707963267948966, 0.0)
>>> tf.transformations.euler_from_quaternion((0, 0.70, 0, 0.70))
(-0.0, 1.5707963267948961, 0.0)
```

Comment: Yes. that was just example. I'll show you my real example tf.transformations.euler_from_quaternion((0.001347211885, 0.706929032, 0.000874635079, 0.7072826612883255))
(1.4132943121198136, 1.567614609686458, 1.412625986733099) This is my problem

Comment: I added some suggestions to my answer.